# Smooth line diagram in google sheets - complex case

Tags: google-sheets

Can you please help me to understand how to build a diagram (smooth line) that is basing on RED values (BLUE category) per GREEN month?

[Table in google sheets](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jb4377bGM-ryQFD7ZwuubXZ4wY7UB9QlGcnDXXjb6Ow/edit?usp=sharing)

I have no idea by this time how to do it - I think diagrams cannot understand multiple values if I just select them separately.

I tried to select individual cells that I need to build diagram for, but it does not work, since it cannot understand that I need to bind the selected cells with months and category names..

Answer (score 2):

The way of doing this would be:

1. Select the first cell of the series
2. Insert chart
3. Select type: smooth line chart
4. Click on `Select data range` (button on the right of the `Data range` input)
5. Click `Add another range` and add the other cells one by one, and then click `OK`
6. Set `Combine ranges` to `Vertically`

And the graph should appear

Comment: Thank you Marti! I tried this as well... as you can see from the link I shared above it does not really work... maybe you know how to manage this issue?

Comment: Try setting the ranges to only the values (`I48,Q48,Y48,AG48,AO48,AW48,BE48,BM48,BU48,CC48,CK48,CS48`). It worked for me

Comment: Hey @Martí I tried. But no success... I feel like I am not getting something simple or I build my sheet completely wrong. Can you please kindly try to look at the link once more? I set it up, but it does not work with separate values.

Comment: @SufficientHappiness It seems like you had an extra range and you had the option `Switch rows and columns` activated. Modified your test sheet (remove edit access, for better future preservation ;)

Comment: Hey thanks a lot! :) I also tried this. But this is not exactly what I wanted... as in this case it does not show the labels in x axis.

Comment: @SufficientHappiness Maybe creating a new sheet and adding the data there may be the simplest solution. Once you have the data together you can make a chart like normal

Comment: Thank you very much for help! I will try this.